# Applescript open new space in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-sierra

I want to open a new Desktop/Space in Mac OS Sierra. For an Alfred Workflow.

I tried it with a Applescript snippet that I found here: 
[Automator + Applescript how to: new Desktop (open Calendar and Reminders in it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165847/automator-applescript-how-to-new-desktop-open-calendar-and-reminders-in-it)

But this one does not seem to work under Mac OS Sierra.

I opened up the Accessibility Inspector and found out that there are two new groups. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Yl6.png

So I tried this:

```
tell process "Dock" to tell group 1 to tell group 1 to tell group 1 to tell button 1 to click`
end tell
```

But it does not click the Button. Maybe someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it with the following script

```
tell application "System Events" to click (every button whose value of 
attribute "AXDescription" is "add desktop") of group "Spaces Bar" of 
group 1 of group "Mission Control" of process "Dock"
```